# Is it presented or present in a classroom

Tags: tense

I found this confusing. Is it "presented" or "present" in the sentence given below:

All the boys presented in the classroom were bored.

Answer (score 3):

It should be "present" because "present" is an adjective that means "physically at a place" whereas "presented" is a past participle that means "to show something":

> All the boys [who were] ***present*** in the classroom were bored.

Here's an example using "presented":

> All the boys have **presented** their projects to the class.

I hope my explanation might have helped you out.  Take care and good luck.